# React Cannot read property 'lastName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to merge data from two API in the new API but I'm getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastName' of undefined`. This is happening because is not finding `lastName` when it missing in API2. In this case, I want to initialize it as empty string if not able to find that in the merged API.

API 1 look:

```
data: {
0: {
id: 1234
company: 'String',
name: 'Test'
}
1: {
id: 2345
company: 'String1',
name: 'Test 1'
}
2: {
id: 3456
company: 'String2',
name: 'Test 2'
}
3: {
id: 4567
company: 'String3',
name: 'Test 3'
}
}
```

API2 look:

```
data: {
0: {
id: 1234
company: 'String',
name: 'Test'
lastName: 'Second'
}
1: {
id: 2345
company: 'String1',
name: 'Test 1'
}
2: {
id: 3456
company: 'String2',
name: 'Test 2'
lastName: 'Second 1'
 }
3: {
id: 4567
company: 'String3',
name: 'Test 3'
lastName: 'Second 3'
}
}
```

Merged API look:

```
data: {
0: {
id: 1234
company: 'String',
name: 'Test'
lastName: 'Second Test' //lastName from API 2 + name from API 1
}
1: {
id: 2345
company: 'String1',
name: 'Test 1'
lastName: '' //lastName from API 2 + name from API 1
}
2: {
id: 3456
company: 'String2',
name: 'Test 2'
lastName: 'Second 1 Test 2' //lastName from API 2 + name from API 1
}
3: {
id: 4567
company: 'String3',
name: 'Test 3'
lastName: 'Second 3 Test 3' //lastName from API 2 + name from API 1
}
```

Fetched data:

```
const [api1, setApi1] = useState([]);
const [api2, setApi2] = useState([]);
const [mergeApi, setMergeAPi] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch('api1')
  .then((response) => {
    setApi1(response);
  });
});

useEffect(() => {
  fetch('api2')
  .then((response) => {
    setApi2(response);
  });
});

useEffect(() => {
  const data = api1.map(getData => {
    const d = api2.find((object) => {
      // return  object.name === api1.name;
      return  object.name === getData.name; 
    });
    return {
      ...api1,
      // name: `${d.name} - ${d.lastName}` 
      name: d ? `${d.name} - ${d.lastName}` : ""; // solution there
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why is the response from your APIs an object when it looks like an array?

Comment: What is data type of api2?  object or array?

Comment: `api1` is your API data object/array, it has no property called `name`, so the `find()` call returns `undefined` because it could not find the object. So then when you call `d.lastName` with an undefined `d`, you get that error.

Comment: I think the problem is that all of your useEffects are running all at once. Try to run the merging useEffect after the fetching api  is finished.

Answer (score 2):

You can use inline `||` operator:

```
${d.lastName || ""}
```

Also you have to change the object here:

```
return  object.name === getData.name; //<----change here.
```

Comment: @alar you have't mentioned in your question.

Comment: It will not help because "d" is indefiled, but not empty object.  ${(d || {}).lastName }

Comment: @Max api2 does have `name` property so it definitely returns the object but in some case it is undefined because api2 does not have `lastName` property but object is there.

Comment: @Jai yes, your update is correct about object.name === getData.name;

Comment: @alar are you sure api2 has data? Check in console log. maybe you are trying to merge before api2 is updated

Comment: one thing for @alar, `.map` method works on arrays. Are you sure you have correct response in a correct format?

Comment: @Jai if there is an object, he would see in console "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'"

Comment: @Max correct. Now i am in doubt after checking the response OP got.

Comment: @alar please address the comments on your question above so we can help you.

Comment: @alar I'm sure you provided fake data. In your real data could be a case when api2 doesn't have same name as in api1. In this case it could be failed

Comment: @Jai, there is one more bug. See in my answer. he returns  ...api1   instead of ...getData

Comment: guys I resolved that by improving ```name: d ? `${d.name} - ${d.lastName}` : "";```

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
  const data = api1.map(getData => {
    const d = api2.find((object) => {
      // return  object.name === api1.name;
      return  object.name === getData.name; //replaced but doesn't work
    });
    return {
      ...api1,
      name: `${d.name} - ${d.lastName}`
    }
  });
});
```

Array.find return `undefined` if there is no matched item on array. so `d` could be `undefind` and therefore code throws error there is no 'lastname' property on `d`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

```
useEffect(() => {
  const data = api1.map(getData => {
    ...
    if (d) {
      return {
        ...getData,
        name: `${d.name} - ${d.lastName}` 
      }
    } else {
      // some code to handle if d is undefined
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this. There could be a case when in your real data could be some name taht not exist in api2.

```
const data = api1.map(getData => {
  const d = api2.find((object) => {
    return  object.name === getData.name; // <---- NOTE THIS
  });

  if (!d) { // <---- NOTE THIS
    return getData 
  }

  return {
    ...getData, // <---- NOTE THIS
    name: `${d.name} - ${d.lastName}`
  }
});
```

idk if you really have id in objects, but I would compare by id, not by name.

```
return  object.id === getData.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.
1) api1 and api2 data look like object, have `Object.values` to get array of values.

2) Change to find function. Checking `obj2.name === obj1.name`

3) check for `d` value before using.

```js
const api1 = {
  0: {
    id: 1234,
    company: "String",
    name: "Test"
  },
  1: {
    id: 2345,
    company: "String1",
    name: "Test 1"
  },
  2: {
    id: 3456,
    company: "String2",
    name: "Test 2"
  },
  3: {
    id: 4567,
    company: "String3",
    name: "Test 3"
  }
};

const api2 = {
  0: {
    id: 1234,
    company: "String",
    name: "Test",
    lastName: "Second"
  },
  1: {
    id: 2345,
    company: "String1",
    name: "Test 1"
  },
  2: {
    id: 3456,
    company: "String2",
    name: "Test 2",
    lastName: "Second 1"
  },
  3: {
    id: 4567,
    company: "String3",
    name: "Test 3",
    lastName: "Second 3"
  }
};

const data = Object.values(api1).map(obj1 => {
  const d = Object.values(api2).find(obj2 => obj2.name === obj1.name);
  return {
    ...obj1,
    name: d ? `${d.name} - ${d.lastName}` : obj1
  };
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: It will not work here. You set a whole object to name:   name: d ? `${d.name} - ${d.lastName}` : obj1

Comment: @Max, good catch. I meant to type 'obj1.name' there. I will update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for that:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const data = api1.map(getData => {
    const d = api2.find((object) => {
      // return  object.name === api1.name;
      return  object.name === getData.name; 
    });
    return {
      ...api1,
      // name: `${d.name} - ${d.lastName}` 
      name: d ? `${d.name} - ${d.lastName}` : ""; // solution there
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: there is also problem with ...api1,    see my answer